# Excel Conditional Formating when deleting columns creates #Ref

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, named-ranges

I have the following conditional formats that use named ranges in a workbook.

```
=INDEX(CalculatedMonth1,ROW($A1))<INDEX(ForecastMonth2, ROW($A1))

=INDEX(CalculatedMonth1,ROW($A1))>INDEX(ForecastMonth2, ROW($A1))+INDEX(ForecastMonth3, ROW($A1))+INDEX(ForecastMonth4, ROW($A1))
```

They work perfectly fine, except if someone deletes a column then the conditional formatting formula changes to:

```
=INDEX(CalculatedMonth1,ROW(#REF!))<INDEX(ForecastMonth2, ROW(#REF!))

=INDEX(CalculatedMonth1,ROW(#REF!))>INDEX(ForecastMonth2, ROW(#REF!))+INDEX(ForecastMonth3, ROW(#REF!))+INDEX(ForecastMonth4, ROW(#REF!))
```

Is there a way I can prevent the $A1 from converting to #REF! or is there another formula that I can use in my conditional format that will not give me this trouble?  The only condition that I have is it must use those named ranges.

Comment: If your CFR starts in row 1 then why not use `ROW()` instead of `ROW($A1)` ? If it starts in row 2 then use `ROW()-1`.

Comment: @jeeped, I didn't know it defaulted to $A1.  That should fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CFR starts in row 1 then why not use `ROW()` instead of `ROW($A1)` ? If it starts in row 2 then use `ROW()-1`.

```
=INDEX(CalculatedMonth1,ROW())<INDEX(ForecastMonth2, ROW())

=INDEX(CalculatedMonth1,ROW())>INDEX(ForecastMonth2, ROW())+INDEX(ForecastMonth3, ROW())+INDEX(ForecastMonth4, ROW())
```

The ROW(...) function either returns the row number of the parameter or whatever row it is on if no parameter is provided. In your case you just want the number 1 when the CFR is evaluated in row 1, 2  when the CFR is evaluated in row 2, etc.

Comment: Jeeped, I thought this soloved my problem but the conditional formating is coming out with different results when I take the $A1 out of the equation.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, this depends on what your applied to: range is. The above only works for an applied to: that starts in row 1. If it started in row 2 then `ROW()` should be `ROW()-1`. All you want is a **1** when the CFR is evaluated in the first row or your applies to: and a 2, 3, 4, etc for subsequent rows.

Comment: Even row one is coming up differently.

Comment: What is the Applies to: range?

Comment: I figured it out - it is because my named range starts on row 3.  Thank you.  It is fixed now.